# How to remove .php from url using htacces

Tags: url-rewrite

I want to remove index.php from my url, please give me solution over this.

Answer (score 2):

step 1: Goto to your site root folder and you can find the htaccess file there.Open it on text editor and find the line #Rewrite Base/ magento. Just replace it with Rewrite Base/

step 2: Then goto your admin panel and enable the Rewrites(set yes for Use Web Server Rewrites). You can find it at System->Configuration->Web->Search Engine Optimization.

step 3: Then goto Cache management page (system cache management ) and refresh your cache and refresh to check the site.

Just with the .htaccess u can try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: hello @swash_nam, if it works for you, you can accept my answer